Incorrectly collapsing Bootstrap 4.1 menu
As part of the modifications on these pages, I modified the behavior of the menu in the sense that it collapses on mobile devices when an item is clicked. It works almost flawlessly, except for one thing. If I first click on a mobile menu that has sub-items, it expands for a moment and then collapses. On further attempts, everything is OK. I am sending a video for a closer idea.
Here is the javascript I was adding.
$( document ).ready( function () {

    $('.navbar-nav>li').on('click', function(){
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    });

} );


this is very close to an answer but I couldn't verify... your selector for finding elements where to attach the click event handler is taking all the .nav-item also if having sub-items. So in the case you showed in the video, 2 events occur: first the subitems expand; and then the navbar is collapsed. So when you expand it again you'll see the subitems already expanded. A solution could be collapsing the navbar only when a subitem is clicked by replacing that .navbar-nav > li with .nav-item:not(.dropdown)

I finally came up with this solution. It could probably be better.
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $('.navbar-nav>li').on('click', function(){
      let $navbarNavLiElement = $( this );
      let $parentElement = $navbarNavLiElement.parent();

      if ($navbarNavLiElement.hasClass("nav-item dropdown") && !$navbarNavLiElement.hasClass("show")) {
        $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('show');
      } else {
          if ($navbarNavLiElement.hasClass("dropdown-togle")) {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('show');
          } else {
            $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
          }
      }
  });
});

